# How to ensure a method is executed in the specific thread in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, chromium

Chromium code infrastructure provides an wonderful debug API that help to ensure a function is executed in the expected thread, e.g.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/remoting/host/local_input_monitor_win.cc&q=belongstocurrent&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=125

```
DCHECK(ui_task_runner_->BelongsToCurrentThread());
```

The BelongsToCurrentThread() will ensure current function is executed in the ui thread loop, otherwise it will crash here.

My question is: is there any similar approach in Android that help the programmer enforce such debug policy on an function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you can check `Thread.currentThread().getId()` to see whether the current thread is the expected one.

For specifically about the UI thread, you can check that

```
Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()
```

Comment: You inspired me! We could name a thread by Thread.setName(), then we could check a thread by this utility:`void threadCheck(String name) {
    if (!Thread.currentThread().getName().equals(name)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Thread check failure! Should run in thread " + name);
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`runOnUiThread()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to make sure it runs on the UI thread.